# Check if android/iOS app installed from web app?

Tags: android, iphone, html

I have an android application, an iOS application, and an HTML5 application and I want to be able to check from my HTML5 app whether users have the Android or iOS app installed.  I understand this can be done natively in both respective platforms, but is there a way to check if a native app is installed from a web app?  I have registered uri schemes on both native apps, is there a way to check from my web if these apps are installed?

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. If you've setup the app to handle URIs, then you can do some hackery to start the app if it's installed and display something else if it's not. You can't do it without launching the app though as far as I know (and it'd be a user privacy issue if you could).

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought but I wanted to be sure!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can check whether app installed or not in iPhone. Probably you can do it in Android, because it gives more control over system level features. In iPhone the application installs in file system with out having the application's name as the file name of the executable.